# Unsupported protocol: jndi with Websphere 6.1 when trying to access a file as a resource

Tags: java, websphere, jndi

I have the problem, that getting a ressource from my archive failed with a `MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: jndi`

The archive is a war file and is deployed into Websphere successfully.

When I try to access some files inside the archive via

```
jndi://server/context/filename
```

I get the `MalformedURLException`.

Comment: showing us some code would be useful

Comment: [JNDI tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/)

Answer (score 1):

URLs with the "jndi" scheme are returned by the ServletContext#getResource method in Tomcat. However, this is non standard (i.e. the J2EE specs don't impose a URL scheme to be used in the return value of that method) and on other application servers it will be different. Always use the ServletContext#getResource method instead of trying to compose the URL directly.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you registered a custom URL handler, "jndi" is not a supported protocol.

Are you trying to read the file through Java code?